# Azure WASABi SecurityNegotiationException

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, autoscaling, wasabi

I'm running into this exception using Azure auto-scaling WASABi.

> Could not retrieve the instance count for hosted service with DNS prefix '**DNS Prefix**'.
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.ServiceManagement.ServiceManagementClientException: The service configuration could not be retrieved from Windows Azure for hosted service with DNS prefix '**DNS Prefix**' in subscription id '**Subscription ID**' and deployment slot 'Staging'.
>
> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'management.core.windows.net'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I have set my service configuration as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<serviceModel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2011/entlib/autoscaling/serviceModel">
  <subscriptions>
    <subscription name="3-Month Free Trial"
                  certificateThumbprint="<Thumbprint>"
                  subscriptionId="<Subscription ID>"
                  certificateStoreLocation="LocalMachine" certificateStoreName="My">
      <services>
        <service dnsPrefix="<DNS Prefix>" slot="Staging">
          <roles>
            <role alias="<Role Name>" roleName="<Role Name>" wadStorageAccountName="wad-control-container"/>
          </roles>
        </service>
      </services>
      <storageAccounts>
        <storageAccount alias="wad-control-container"
                        connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<Account Name>;AccountKey=<Account Key>">
        </storageAccount>
      </storageAccounts>
    </subscription>
  </subscriptions>
  <stabilizer scaleUpCooldown="00:01:00"
            scaleDownCooldown="00:01:00"
            scaleUpOnlyInFirstMinutesOfHour="0"
            scaleDownOnlyInLastMinutesOfHour="0" />
</serviceModel>
```

To add on, the auto-scaling role is a single Worker Role.
The deployment is having 2 Web Role for the website and this auto-scaling Worker Role together.

The web role is using the same certificate and is working fine, could anyone shed some light on what I can look into to solve this issue?

Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: I'm reading up on [Web Role Service definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557553.aspx).
Do I need to open a end point for **SSL/TLS secure channel**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.

1. Create a new certificate
2. Upload to the **Subscription - Certificate**
3. Upload to **Settings - Management Certificate**
4. Add certificate thumbprint to both web and worker roles in VS Studio
5. Set certificateStoreLocation to CurrentUser in **service xml** and **service definition**
6. Redeploy

Hope this help anyone who had this issue.

Cheers.

Comment: cheers this saved my day! the thing that made the difference for me was CurrentUser instead of LocalMachine. With CurrentUser it works!! Thanks